# Classification - compute residual error

Tags: classification, residuals

I'm new to the field of time series forecasting and would like to know if what I think I'm doing makes sense.
I'm looking to do a classification model to have a positive/negative indicator of power volume.

I've tested random forest models, gradient boosting models, but it doesn't give conclusive results.

I've done some research on residual error models that would allow me to consider the errors of my model on its previous predictions. But I have only seen applications for regression models.
In classification, there doesn't seem to be a solution to calculate the residual error.
I thought that a solution to calculate the residual error could be to consider the probability of the predicted class. such as: `error = 1-prob_class`

Does anyone have an opinion on this? Or an article/document about it? I can't find anything special.
Do you think I can get anything out of it?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a proper scoring rule like Brier score or log loss. If you read about those briefly, do they accomplish what you want to do? If not, please say why so we can discuss.

Comment: did not know these scoring methods, that's exactly what i need, I will check this out, thanks a lot!